# Handling asynchronous task completion when Activity is in or out of focus

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I have the following Android scenario:

my activity launches an asynchronous task to perform background activity (`AsyncTask` class), and then searches for accounts. If no account is present, UI to create a new account is invoked via the `AbstractAuthenticator` while the previous AsyncTask still runs.

The task will eventually complete and run onPostExecute on the main thread of my previous activity.

My problem is the following: if the task completes when my activity is on top, an `AlertDialog` is correctly displayed; instead, if the task completes while the user is entering username/password for the new account, I get an `InvocationTargetException` when trying to show the alert.

Actually, the AlertDialog must be shown only when activity is active. I can modify my code and take advantage of `onStart` method with the following pseudo code:

```
public class MyActivity {
    private boolean displayAlertOnStart = false;

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if (displayAlertOnStart){
            displayAlert();
            displayAlertOnStart = false;
        }
    }


    private void handleTaskCallback() {
        if (activityIsOnTop()) //How do I get this???
           displayAlert();
        else
           displayAlertOnStart = true;
    }
```

I would like to programmatically know if the current activity is "on top" or another activity is foreground. This way I'll do my logic when running the onStart the next time.

Any other (and simpler) solutions welcome. SDK 7.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use a state variable in the onStart() and onStop() method to maintain the state of the Activity?

```
public class MyActivity {
    private boolean displayAlertOnStart = false;
    private boolean activityInAStartedState = false;

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        activityInAStartedState = true;

        if (displayAlertOnStart){
            displayAlert();
            displayAlertOnStart = false;
        }
    }

    public void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       activityInAStartedState = false;
    }


    private void handleTaskCallback() {
        if (activityInAStartedState) 
           displayAlert();
        else
           displayAlertOnStart = true;
      }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the existence of the onStop method. I was going to write this as my own answer :). Question remains open for further feedback on "how to handle the completion of asynchronous tasks in or out of focus". But I think we have a winner :)

Comment: I think this does it all. The only other important thing, is canceling your AsyncTask in your onDestroy() method, so that the AsyncTask does not invoke handleTaskCallback() in a context-dead object.

Comment: Even if activity can be finish()ed only and only after task completion?

Comment: The system can always chose to destroy your Activity: in a dignified way by invoking onDestroy() or in a brutal way, by not.

Comment: If it does so the brutal way, you cant do anything, though you'll be leaving an orphan AsyncTask. Though this scenario doesn't happen often, if it is critical, you need to think about this.

Comment: AFAIK Android OS closes processes by brutally killing them at any time, unlike what happens on the emulator. But I didn't know that single activities in a stack could be softly or hardly killed

Comment: Here's onDestroy() from the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy(). It talks about the non-brutal murder!

Comment: Here's a good reference I found that describes what methods get called when Activies are created, paused, and destroyed by the user and OS.  http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/activity-lifecycle-explained-in-details/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no method that lets you know if an activity is visible.

One way around this would be keeping a variable in your Application class which signifies if this Activity is on top.  To implement this, you'll need to manage it in your Activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods.  Create a variable, something like `private boolean myActivityOnTop = false` with static getter and setter methods.  In `onPause()`, set this variable to false, and make it true again in `onResume`.  Then replace `isActivityOnTop()` with the getter method. You could do the same thing if you want to know which of a number of Activities is on top by making this an int, string, or enum and setting it whenever any of the activities' `onResume` is called.

Also, just a tip, whenever an Activity is pushed to the background, there is no guarantee that Android will not destroy it.  It is possible that you set `displayAlertOnStart` to true, but the Activity is then destroyed.  When it restarts upon being brought back to the front, the Activity will be recreated and will not know to display the Dialog.  Any variables that you'll want to maintain after starting a new activity should be Bundled in `onSaveInstanceState()` and re-initialized in `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.